# Camel Apache: How to put variable in a url?

Tags: json, apache-camel, unmarshalling, dynamic-url

I need to create a route (or not only one) that will do the following:

1. Read some ids from a .txt file (tokenized by `/n`)
2. For each id I will make a GET request to an url (`http://myexample.com/something/**id**`)
3. Every request will bring me a JSON
4. JSON will be unmarshaled to XML

So, I need a JSON file for every id in my file.txt. If I have 10 ids, I will get 10 JSON files from that url. I made the component that take me JSONs from a folder and unmarshal them to XML. Also, I tokenized my `file.txt`.

The problem is I don't know how to get a JSON file per each id, more exactly, how can I dynamically transform my url?

My code is:

```
<camel:route id="getRequestForEachId">
            <camel:from uri="file:src/main/resources/idList?noop=true" />
            <camel:split>
                <camel:tokenize token="\n" />
                <camel:to uri="stream:out" />
                 <camel:recipientList>
                    <camel:simple>
                     http://myexample.com/something/${body}
                    </camel:simple>
                </camel:recipientList> 
                <camel:to uri="file:src/main/resources/jsonMandatFromReq" />
                <!--from this will take my json->xml component-->
            </camel:split>
</camel:route>
```

And with this code I get a 405 error:

```
HTTP operation failed invoking http://google.com/something/3 with statusCode: 405
```

That `3` is from `file.txt` with ids. So the url is built somehow, but I end with exceptions.

I would love concrete help, not a url to dynamic url on the camel site. Thank you very much!

**LE:**

The below answer solved my main problem, but I'm having another one now.
The GET method won't stop from making requests.

I want to have just one request for each id, and for this I'll get a JSON file per each request or id.
But my route is making requests continuously. After the list with ids is ending, it begins again. So I end with many JSON files for one id, when I need just one JSON file per id.

I don't want to override the existing JSON file. I want to have just one GET request per each id.
How can I solve this?

Comment: Error code 405 means "Method not allowed" so maybe the request method is not being set to GET? Try adding `<setHeader headerName="CamelHttpMethod><constant>GET</constant></setHeader>` before your recipient list

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I'm ending with a 500 error, but it's ok. I can receive the only available JSON for one id, so I think this works.
Thank you so much!

Comment: Still having a problem. I can't make the GET stop from making requests. I mean, after the request is made for all the ids, the GET is starting again and make me another jsons, so I end with more than 1 JSON file per id. I end with a lot of JSONs for a single id.
Any idea on how can I solve this?